# Associate Extensions in Windows CE

Tags: associations, windows-ce, file-association

How can I associate an extension of a file to an program in Windows CE? It's so boring to run my Python programs using *cmd*. If I associate Python with my **.py* files I'm going to run my program faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching in the Python files under my Windows CE and i found a simple code to do this, and i tweaked it to be better:

```
#
#   Setup the registry to allow us to double click on python scripts
#

from _winreg import *

print "Setting up registry to allow\ndouble clicking of Python files to work"

#
#   Create the registry entries for ".py" and ".pyc" extensions
#

for Name in (".py", ".pyc"):
    Key = CreateKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, Name)
    SetValue(Key, None, REG_SZ, "Python.File")
    CloseKey(Key)

#
#   Create HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\Open\Command = "\Program Files\Python\Lib\Python.exe" "%1"
#

Key = CreateKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "Python.File")
for Name in ("Shell","Open","Command"):
  New_Key= CreateKey(Key, Name)
  CloseKey(Key)
  Key = New_Key
SetValue(Key, None, REG_SZ, "\"\\Program Files\\Python\\Lib\\Python.exe\" \"%1\"")
CloseKey(Key)

import time
time.sleep(5)
```

This is the code, if you want you can use it to associate to other programs and other extensions.

Comment: If you copy code verbatim from another source it is customary to give credit. This was copied from: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonce/2006-January/001286.html